# accessing nan values from array of arays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to find where nans are in this column, change it to a different value and update the dataset. I was able to access the nan by using [0][0] for this example but this solution will not work if I don't know where the nans are. I'm hoping someone can suggest how can we dynamically search for nans and change them when they happen to be in array of arrays.

```
def check_for_nan():
    data = {'numbers': [[np.nan], [11, 14], [45, 56], [67, 88], [99]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    df["numbers"][0][0] = 40
    print(df["numbers"])
```

Desired Output:

```
0        [40]
1    [11, 14]
2    [45, 56]
3    [67, 88]
4        [99]
Name: numbers, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
Expands ['numbers'] into separate columns

```
df=df['numbers'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Locates rows with nans

```
df_nan=df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Assign values to specific nan cells:

```
df_nan.at[0,0]=40
df_nan.at[4,1]=41
```

Place values back in original data frame

```
df=df.fillna(df_nan)
```

Back to original format

```
df['combined']=df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).tolist()
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I just ran it and I'm not sure I understand what's going on

Comment: So the first line expands the lists contained in the 'numbers' into separate columns and then you just locate the rows which contain 'nan'.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to change the nan values to a different values, similar to what I wrote in the post:
df["numbers"][0][0] = 40
Using your example, how can I change the nan value to 40 for example?

Comment: I expanded my previous answer.  Please see if it helps.

Comment: I don't think that's still answering my question. Your solution prints [40.0, nan], which means it's adding 40.0 to the nan array rather then replacing the nan with 40. The desired output would be [40.0] rather than [40.0, nan]

Comment: Change the last line to df['combined']=df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).tolist().  This should work

Comment: that worked thanks! One more thing, in my original post I mentioned that using [0][0] will not work if I don't know where the nans are. Can we find where the nans are and change it to the value 40 more dynamically?